# Timezone conversion in Bash script

Tags: bash, time-zone

I found a solution about how to convert time zone with the Linux `date` command:
[Timezone conversion by command line](https://superuser.com/questions/164339/timezone-conversion-by-command-line/164354#164354)

```
$ date --date='TZ="Asia/Taipei" 18:00'
Fri Jul 16 11:00:00 BST 2010
```

It's working great, but I can't figure it out how to use it in a Bash script, when time is a variable, like:

```
TIME=18:00
DATE="`date --date='TZ="Asia/Taipei" $TIME' +%F\ %H:%M`"
echo $DATE;
```

I have problems with escaping special characters. And I totally don't understand why the `date` command works with timezones like [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time), [EET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Time), etc. and not with timezones like "Asia/Taipei", Europe/Moscow, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a section titled *QUOTING* in `man bash`. I suggest you read it, or the [Bash Reference Manual on quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html).

A correct command line would be:

```
DATE=$( date --date="TZ=\"Asia/Taipei\" $TIME" +%F\ %H:%M )
```

- [Using `$( )` prevents some quoting issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) that occur with backticks.
- You need to double-quote both the time zone (apparently for formatting reasons), *and* double-quote the argument to allow variable substitution, so just escape the inner quotes once.

---

I'm not sure what you're asking in your last paragraph, but note that the mapping from continent/city to time zone isn't bijective. Given a date and time in a time zone, you won't be able to find out what city that is. Multiple files in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` have the same time zone information. Additionally, it depends on *when* you execute the command, due to daylight savings time, areas changing their entire time zone, or other [date related weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/23222).